# Is SurfaceView hardware-accelerated?

Tags: android, opengl-es-1.1

I am displaying `Bitmaps` in my `SurfaceView` using `Canvas.drawBitmap`. My phone has GPU.

Then I've changed from `SurfaceView` to `GLSurfaceView` , displaying bitmaps with `GLUtils.texImage2D` from `Renderer`'s `onDrawFrame()` every time.

I didn't notice any difference in speed (although I didn't do exact measurements, just by observation).

Shall there be a difference or is it meaningless to use `GLSurfaceView` for textures only,  does `SurfaceView` provide the necessary  hardware acceleration support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is not, and adding HW acceleration is not planned for the next Android release.

Cf. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/ly-DqqZyPTw/XZNJmHpVBGoJ

If you do more thorough benchmarking you should see the difference.

Comment: All I did were textures. I'm afraid I don't understand how textures are speeded up by OpenGL?

Comment: Sorry, missed the textures bit. I know for sure that SurfaceView is not HW accelerated. I don't know whether GLSurfaceView will give you a speedup.

Answer (score 0):

Years later this has changed. Android's SurfaceView does offer hardware acceleration since Android 8 via [SurfaceHolder.lockHardwareCanvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder#lockHardwareCanvas()).